# Display normal vectors with open3d.visualization.O3DVisualizer

Tags: python, visualization, open3d, visualizer

I'm using the amazing open3d Python libary to visualize some point Cloud. I already know the normal vectors of these points that I attribute directly as follows:

```
pcd         = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
pcd.points  = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(points)
pcd.normals = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(normals)
```

I am also setting a visualizer in which I insert these points as follows:

```
app = gui.Application.instance
app.initialize()
vis = o3d.visualization.O3DVisualizer("Open3D - 3D Text", 1024, 768)
vis.show_settings = True
vis.add_geometry("my points", pcd)
with o3d.utility.VerbosityContextManager(o3d.utility.VerbosityLevel.Debug) as cm:        
    '''visualize'''
    vis.reset_camera_to_default()
    app.add_window(vis)
    app.run()
```

Up to now, all of this has run as intended, however I am not able to set the visualizer in such a way that enables me to visualize the normal vectors. Apparently o3d.visualization.Visualizer() has this method get_render_option() that is said to "retrieve a RenderOption" object, and in this RenderOption object there is a point_show_normal property but I couldn't make my code (more complicated than the minimal example above) work with o3d.visualization.Visualizer(): I don't see how to use this o3d.visualization.Visualizer().get_render_option().point_show_normal.

Is there any way to show the normal vectors with with open3d.visualization.O3DVisualizer?

Answer (score 1):

you need add two lines to your code, get the render and set *point_show_normal* to True:

```
opt = vis.get_render_option()
opt.point_show_normal = True
```

You can see in the documentation [open3D](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/index.html) tutorials and python examples

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a solution so far, so I resorted to look at my normal vectors in another window, produced using the mayavi library rather than the open3D library. To do so, I used this simple code snippet:

```
 from   mayavi.mlab       import *

 P = [my list of 3D points]
 N = [my list of normal vectors]

 x = P[:, 0]                        
 y = P[:, 1]                        
 z = P[:, 2]                        
 points3d(x, y, z, color=(0, 1, 0), scale_factor=0.5)                                                                                                  

 u = N[:, 0]                        
 v = N[:, 1]                        
 w = N[:, 2]                        
 quiver3d(x, y, z, u, v, w)         
 show()
```

And it worked as intended. Ideally I would like to have the normal vectors displayed with the rest of the figure, but this responded to my immediate needs.

I consider this as a workaround rather than the definitive solution, so I put it here as an answer if someone else having the problem finds it useful. But my question still isn't solved.